# Replacing all images with something else

Tags: javascript, image, replace, vbulletin

I'm running a vbulletin forum with https, it runs well and all, but when someone posts an image the https gives a warning. I've found a way to combat this but I need some help!

How can I replace all images on page, which arent hosting on example.com with example.com/outimage.php?img=http://whattheurltotheimagewas.com/picture.png

Ithink will be needed to be done in javascript, im not sure.

Could anyone else me out?

Thanks

edit: just incase it matters, here is the outimage.php

```
<?php

$file = isset($_GET['img']) && !empty($_GET['img']) ? $_GET['img'] : false;

if(!$file) {
  echo 'Invalid IMG URL';
  exit;
}

$ext = substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1);

switch($ext) {
  case 'jpg': case 'jpe': case 'jpeg':
    $type = 'jpeg';
    break;
  default:
    $type = $ext;
    break;
}

if(!in_array($ext, array('png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp'))) {
  echo 'Invalid Image.';
  exit;
}

header('Content-type:  image/'. $type);
readfile($file);
header("Location: $_GET[img]"); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud be able to edit the BBCodes that the forum has, which means you can insert your "proxy" PHP script url into it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own plugin to do string replacement like this.
Go to **admincp** > **add new plugin**.

- Hook location : **postbit_display_complete**
- Title : anything
- Execution Order : 5 (default)
- Plugin PHP Code :

  ```
  $post['message'] = str_replace('STRING_FROM', 'STRING_TO', $post['message']);
  ```

Click Save button.